# MongoDB Atlas replicaSet name

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

Where can i find the replica set name in MongoDB atlas beause i keep getting this :

MongoError: seed list contains no mongos proxies, replicaset connections requires the parameter replicaSet to be supplied in the URI or options object, mongodb://server:port/db?replicaSet=name

Comment: mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://root:root@node-rest-shop-v7e3s.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true',
                 { useNewUrlParser: true ,
                 });

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find the replica set name in the Atlas control panel.

1. From the Clusters view, click Connect for the cluster you want
2. Click Connect Your Application
3. Click I am using driver 3.4 or earlier.
4. Look at the connection string; it contains a substring "replicaSet=myAtlasRS" with your replica set name.

More details here:

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/mongomirror/#copy-the-target-cluster-host-information

Comment: Unfortunately using the current MongoDB Atlas web-based interface the option #3 - "Click I am using driver 3.4 or earlier" is no longer available.

Comment: @barrypicker see my newer answer

Comment: UPDATE: Currently you should select driver **2.2.12 or later** to see the replicaSet name

Comment: This was needed to connect with Robo/Studio 3T

Answer (score 9):

With the **new MongoAtlas UI**, you can find the replica set name in the Atlas control panel as follows:

1. From the Clusters view, click Connect for the cluster you want
2. Connect with the Mongo shell
3. Click 'I have the Mongo shell installed'
4. Select driver: 3.4 or earlier.
5. Look at the connection string; it contains a substring "replicaSet=myAtlasRS" with your replica set name.